# Plot Date Hour in R - transform column

Tags: r

I have a list with four columns. The first one is titled (in German, sorry) as "Date and Time" and the other three ones contain data of the amount of the fallen rain.

I am able to bar-plot "Date and Time" and one of the other columns in Excel with no problems. But I want to solve this problem in R. The problem is - I think - the format of the "Date and Time" Column. The result of my try to bar-plot "Date and Time" against another column is a totally black plot with different y-labs.

Can you guys help me how to transform the "Date and Time"-Column so R is able to understand what I want? And my other question is: Sometimes I need a normal plot, other times I need a bar-plot. Does that mean I have to transform the "Date and Time"-Column in two different ways?

Here is my code and the first rows of the table I am talking about:

**#### Code**

```
Daten1_12_10 csv("daten1_12_10.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";")
```

**#### Daten1_12_10**

```
Datum und Zeit Waage in mm Kippwaage in mm Waechter in min
01.12.10 18:01 0 0 0
01.12.10 18:02 0 0 0
01.12.10 18:03 0 0 0
01.12.10 18:04 0 0 0
01.12.10 18:05 0 0 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to combine your date and time columns, and convert them to a time object using `as.POSIXct`. You can then use the time column to do your plotting.

```
dat <- read.table(text = "01.12.10 18:01 0 0 0
                          01.12.10 18:02 0 0 0
                          01.12.10 18:03 0 0 0
                          01.12.10 18:04 0 0 0
                          01.12.10 18:05 0 0 0")

dat$time <- as.POSIXct(paste(dat$V1, dat$V2), format = "%m.%d.%y %H:%M")
dat$vals <- 1:5

plot(dat$vals ~ dat$time)
```

[image]

You should take a look at `?strptime`.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform your data referred to the date by using `asDate()` function on this basis:

```
df$new.date <- as.Date(df$old.date, "%m-%d-%Y")
```

Where %m %d %Y refer to month, day and year. Since these may have different formats, these arguments may change. Besides, there are other functions that can deal with this (`as.POSIXct` or `POSIXlt`) and enable to introduce the time (e.g. hours, minutes and seconds) variables. For doing that you should aggregate with `paste()` and then use `striptime()`. For example dealing with a variable that include date and time will be something like this.

```
as.POSIXct(strptime("2011-03-27 01:30:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Comment: Your answer is really a duplicate of the answer I gave.